# Extract missing labels in given language

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm kinda web developer but need to to some back-end coding right now. Is there any solution for it.

First of all i need To extract missing labels in given language

It should be javascript file to be run with Node, that javascript file receives resources file name and resource language as input, i.e. “node extract-missing-labels.js labels.json cz-CZ” and then it should produce the JSON file with exactly the same structure as the original labels file, just with a single language (cz-CZ in my example) and containing only the missing labels.
P.S labels is text written buttons or any content on web application.

There is original labels.json file

```
"Shell": {
        "Profile": "Profile",
        "SignOut": "Sign out",
        "CloseView": "Close current view",
        "Settings": "Settings",
        "ModifySettings": "Modify settings",
        "SettingsModified": "Settings have been changed",
        "Help": "Help"
}
```

so i did a parse for the json file, but now i dont know how i should do my javascript file to Receive resources file name and resource language as input.

Comment: I tried to parse some data but i think i should think in other way.So probably nothing because i dont know exactly how to implement it. There is no info even how to do it. So need an example.

Comment: You should google, start coding and then when you have a problem, go back here :( You can check http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: that's actually true ;)